# How to sort value of multiple array in single foreach loop?

Tags: php

I am using the following code to show the player name and the number of goals.But the problem is it is not positioning based on the number of goals.
My objective is to rank the player based on the goal number; more goal top position.
I need someone to help.

```
$top_player_names = rwmb_meta( 'pb_player_rank', array( 'multiple' => false ) );   
  $goals     = rwmb_meta( 'pb_goal_number','', get_the_ID() ); 
  foreach( $top_player_names as $index => $top_player_name ) {?>
    <li class="col-md-12"> 
    <div class="col-md-8"><?php  echo get_the_title($top_player_name); ?></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><?php  echo $goals[$index]; ?></div>

    </li>
   <?php }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sort the `$goals` array with `asort($goals);`
2. Use the foreach on `$goals` instead of `$top_player_names`

Your code could look like this:

```
$top_player_names = rwmb_meta( 'pb_player_rank', array( 'multiple' => false ) );   
  $goals     = rwmb_meta( 'pb_goal_number','', get_the_ID() ); 
  asort($goals);
  foreach( $goals as $index => $goal ) {?>
    <li class="col-md-12"> 
    <div class="col-md-8"><?php  echo get_the_title($top_player_names[$index]); ?></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><?php  echo $goals[$index]; ?></div>

    </li>
   <?php }
```

I think that's the easiest and fastest way to solve this problem.

Comment: the asort should be 2 lines below I guess

Comment: Yes Hahaha :) Ty for mentioning that

Comment: @Armin Šupuk well but if two values are equal then?

Comment: @attoma Depends on what you want to achieve, `usort` can take a custom sort function. Link: http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php